# How can I teach Tcl to automatically print my object with a proc I provide?

Tags: printing, tcl, decorator

I have an object that Tcl shows in the console as being its object id.  How can I extend Tcl such that whenever objects of my type are printed, a special proc is automatically called that I provide to print their contents instead of just giving the object id?

Some more details: I am emulating a lisp list in Tcl which is built up out of cons cells that each have a car and a cdr. The list of 1 "two" 3 would be created with:

```
(cons 1 (cons "two" (cons 3 nil)))
```

which creates 3 cons cells.  The top cons cell that has 1 in its car has a pointer to the second cons cell that has "two" in its car, etc.

With this representation, I wish for the above sample list to print out as:

```
(1 "two" 3)
```

Comment: What is producing those object ids? Is the object capable of being completely described by its string representation?

Comment: @Donal Fellows I've expanded the question to give more details. It is the cons cell that has an object id.  A cons cell can be described by a string that holds the pointer value to the object's location in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're working at the C level. Basically, you register a function to do this in your `Tcl_ObjType` structure, in the `updateStringProc` field. Your function will need to produce a string rendering of your overall value (stored in a `ckalloc`ed string in the `bytes` field of the `Tcl_Obj`); how to do so is up to you.

Comment: Yes I am using C++ here.  Will this change the string representation of the object for Tcl?  If so, will that cause trouble if the string representation evaluated does not get you back to the same object again?

Comment: @WilliamKF: Yes, but what does “the same object” mean to you? In the standard Tcl interpretation, two objects are the same if they look the same (hence the claim that “everything is a string”; it isn't but it is a convenient proxy for the real semantics). If you want to have identity apart from representation (e.g., so you can assign to a particular part of the object) then you've got to go with the handle approach and use an explicit command to get the representation. Tcl's value system is *quite* different to that of many other languages, which has both plusses and minuses.

Comment: The big plusses are that Tcl tends to share literals and values far more than other languages, and a simple reference counting system is generally adequate for “GC”. The big minus is that sharing values with other (scripting) languages is difficult because of the totally different model of identity; Tcl doesn't sit well with many bytecode engines because of this.